Taming the ArrowHead antipattern
How can I best refactor the code below in order to cleanse it of the ArrowHead antipattern? (Note: this represents a subset of the full code as originally discussed here.)
Public Class DnsService
  Implements IDnsService

  Public Sub New(Client As ICloudFlareClient)
    Me.Client = Client
  End Sub

  Public Async Function RegisterAsync(City As City, IPAddresses As List(Of IPAddress)) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.RegisterAsync
    Return Await Me.UpdateAsync(City, DnsRecordType.A, IPAddresses.Select(Function(Address) Address.ToString))
  End Function

  Public Async Function AddTokenAsync(City As City, DnsText As String) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.AddTokenAsync
    Return Await Me.UpdateAsync(City, DnsRecordType.Txt, {DnsText})
  End Function

  Public Async Function UpdateAsync(City As City, RecordType As DnsRecordType, Values As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.UpdateAsync
    Dim oDnsRecordsResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oDnsRecordResult As CloudFlareResult(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oModifiedRecord As ModifiedDnsRecord
    Dim oCurrentRecord As DnsRecord
    Dim oZonesResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone))
    Dim sRecordName As String
    Dim oNewRecord As NewDnsRecord
    Dim oFilter As DnsRecordFilter
    Dim oResult As Result
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim oZone As Zone

    oZonesResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.GetAsync
    sRecordName = If(RecordType = DnsRecordType.Txt, City.AcmeChallengeDnsName, City.CertificateCommonName)

    If oZonesResult.Success Then
      oResult = Result.Ok
      oZone = oZonesResult.Result.First

      For Each sValue In Values
        oFilter = New DnsRecordFilter With {.Type = RecordType, .Name = sRecordName, .Content = sValue}
        oDnsRecordsResult = Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.GetAsync(oZone.Id, oFilter).Result

        If oDnsRecordsResult.Success Then
          If oDnsRecordsResult.Result.Any Then
            oCurrentRecord = oDnsRecordsResult.Result.First
            oModifiedRecord = New ModifiedDnsRecord With {.Type = RecordType, .Name = oCurrentRecord.Name, .Content = sValue}
            oDnsRecordResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.UpdateAsync(oZone.Id, oCurrentRecord.Id, oModifiedRecord)

            ' Clean up any stale duplicates
            For Each oCurrentRecord In oDnsRecordsResult.Result.Skip(1)
              oDnsRecordResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.DeleteAsync(oZone.Id, oCurrentRecord.Id)
              If Not oDnsRecordResult.Success Then Exit For
            Next
          Else
            oNewRecord = New NewDnsRecord With {.Type = RecordType, .Name = sRecordName, .Content = sValue}
            oDnsRecordResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.AddAsync(oZone.Id, oNewRecord)
          End If

          If Not oDnsRecordResult.Success Then
            oResult = Result.Fail(oDnsRecordResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
          End If
        Else
          oResult = Result.Fail(oDnsRecordsResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
        End If

        If oResult.IsFailed Then Exit For
      Next
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oZonesResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Friend Async Function CleanupAsync(City As City) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.CleanupAsync
    Dim oDnsRecordsResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oDnsRecordResult As CloudFlareResult(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oCurrentRecord As DnsRecord
    Dim oZonesResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone))
    Dim oDnsRecord As (Type As DnsRecordType, Name As String)
    Dim oFilter As DnsRecordFilter
    Dim oResult As Result
    Dim oZone As Zone

    oDnsRecord.Type = DnsRecordType.Txt
    oDnsRecord.Name = City.AcmeChallengeDnsName

    oZonesResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.GetAsync

    If oZonesResult.Success Then
      oZone = oZonesResult.Result.First
      oFilter = New DnsRecordFilter With {.Type = oDnsRecord.Type, .Name = oDnsRecord.Name}
      oDnsRecordsResult = Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.GetAsync(oZone.Id, oFilter).Result

      If oDnsRecordsResult.Success Then
        If oDnsRecordsResult.Result.Any Then
          oCurrentRecord = oDnsRecordsResult.Result.First
          oDnsRecordResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.DeleteAsync(oZone.Id, oCurrentRecord.Id)

          ' Clean up any stale duplicates
          For Each oCurrentRecord In oDnsRecordsResult.Result.Skip(1)
            oDnsRecordResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.DeleteAsync(oZone.Id, oCurrentRecord.Id)
            If Not oDnsRecordResult.Success Then Exit For
          Next

          If oDnsRecordResult.Success Then
            oResult = Result.Ok
          Else
            oResult = Result.Fail(oDnsRecordResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
          End If
        Else
          oResult = Result.Fail(My.Resources.Errors.DnsNoRecordsFound.ToFormat(oDnsRecord.Type.ToString.ToUpper, oDnsRecord.Name))
        End If
      Else
        oResult = Result.Fail(oDnsRecordsResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
      End If
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oZonesResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function GetZones() As Task(Of Result(Of CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone))))
    Return Await Me.Client.Zones.GetAsync
  End Function

  Private ReadOnly Client As ICloudFlareClient
End Class


I tried refactoring to the Rules pattern, as suggested here, but after time even that solution became overwhelmingly complex. I ended up settling on the Railway pattern, which worked out very nicely in the end.
While I do concede that it resulted in nearly twice the actual lines of code, it's far more readable and maintainable. Meaning more stable and more testable.
If anyone has suggestions for further improvement, I'm all ears.
DnsService
Public Class DnsService
  Implements IDnsService

  Public Sub New(Client As ICloudFlareClient)
    Me.Client = Client
  End Sub

  Public Async Function RegisterAsync(City As City, IPAddresses As List(Of IPAddress)) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.RegisterAsync
    Return Await Me.UpdateAsync(City, DnsRecordType.A, IPAddresses.Select(Function(Address) Address.ToString))
  End Function

  Public Async Function AddTokenAsync(City As City, DnsText As String) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.AddTokenAsync
    Return Await Me.UpdateAsync(City, DnsRecordType.Txt, {DnsText})
  End Function

  Friend Async Function UpdateAsync(
    City As City,
    RecordType As DnsRecordType,
    RecordContents As IEnumerable(Of String)
  ) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.UpdateAsync

    Dim oGetZone As Func(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone), Task(Of Result(Of Zone)))
    Dim oProcess As Func(Of Zone, Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord)))
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    oGetZone = Async Function(Zones) Await Task.FromResult(Zones.First.ToResult)
    oProcess = Async Function(Zone) Await Me.ProcessInputAsync(Zone, RecordType, RecordContents, City)

    oResult =
      Await (
        Await (
          Await Me.GetZonesAsync
        ).CallAsync(oGetZone)
      ).CallAsync(oProcess)

    Return If(oResult.IsSuccess, Result.Ok, Result.Fail(oResult.Errors))
  End Function

  Friend Async Function CleanupAsync(City As City) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.CleanupAsync
    Dim oGetZone As Func(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone), Task(Of Result(Of Zone)))
    Dim oProcess As Func(Of Zone, Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord)))
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    oGetZone = Async Function(Zones) Await Task.FromResult(Zones.First.ToResult)
    oProcess = Async Function(Zone) Await Me.ProcessCleanupAsync(Zone, City)

    oResult =
      Await (
        Await (
          Await Me.GetZonesAsync
        ).CallAsync(oGetZone)
      ).CallAsync(oProcess)

    Return If(oResult.IsSuccess, Result.Ok, Result.Fail(oResult.Errors))
  End Function

  Private Async Function GetZonesAsync() As Task(Of Result(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone)))
    Dim oCfResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone))
    Dim oResult As Result(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone))

    oCfResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.GetAsync

    If oCfResult.Success Then
      oResult = oCfResult.Result.ToResult
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oCfResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function ProcessInputAsync(
    Zone As Zone,
    RecordType As DnsRecordType,
    RecordContents As IEnumerable(Of String),
    City As City
  ) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))

    Dim oAddOrUpdate As Func(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord), Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord)))
    Dim sRecordName As String
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oFilter As DnsRecordFilter

    sRecordName = If(RecordType = DnsRecordType.Txt, City.AcmeChallengeDnsName, City.CertificateCommonName)
    oResult = Result.Ok

    For Each sRecordContent In RecordContents
      oFilter = New DnsRecordFilter With {.Content = sRecordContent, .Name = sRecordName, .Type = RecordType}
      oAddOrUpdate = Async Function(DnsRecords)
                       Return _
                         Await Me.AddOrUpdateRecordAsync(
                           Zone,
                           RecordType,
                           sRecordContent,
                           sRecordName,
                           DnsRecords
                         )
                     End Function

      oResult =
        Await (
          Await Me.GetRecordsAsync(Zone, oFilter)
        ).CallAsync(oAddOrUpdate)

      If oResult.IsFailed Then Exit For
    Next

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function ProcessCleanupAsync(Zone As Zone, City As City) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oDelete As Func(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord), Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord)))
    Dim oFilter As DnsRecordFilter

    oFilter = New DnsRecordFilter With {.Type = DnsRecordType.Txt, .Name = City.AcmeChallengeDnsName}
    oDelete = Async Function(DnsRecords) Await Me.DeleteRecordsAsync(Zone, DnsRecords)

    Return _
      Await (
        Await Me.GetRecordsAsync(Zone, oFilter)
      ).CallAsync(oDelete)
  End Function

  Private Async Function GetRecordsAsync(
    Zone As Zone,
    Filter As DnsRecordFilter
  ) As Task(Of Result(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord)))

    Dim oCfResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oResult As Result(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord))

    oCfResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.GetAsync(Zone.Id, Filter)

    If oCfResult.Success Then
      oResult = oCfResult.Result.ToResult
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oCfResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function AddOrUpdateRecordAsync(
    Zone As Zone,
    RecordType As DnsRecordType,
    RecordContent As String,
    RecordName As String,
    DnsRecords As IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord)
  ) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))

    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    If DnsRecords.Any Then
      oResult = Await Me.UpdateRecordAsync(Zone, RecordType, RecordContent, DnsRecords)
    Else
      oResult = Await Me.AddRecordAsync(Zone, RecordType, RecordContent, RecordName)
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function AddRecordAsync(
    Zone As Zone,
    RecordType As DnsRecordType,
    RecordContent As String,
    RecordName As String
  ) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))

    Dim oNewRecord As NewDnsRecord
    Dim oCfResult As CloudFlareResult(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    oNewRecord = New NewDnsRecord With {.Type = RecordType, .Name = RecordName, .Content = RecordContent}
    oCfResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.AddAsync(Zone.Id, oNewRecord)

    If oCfResult.Success Then
      oResult = oCfResult.Result.ToResult
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oCfResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function UpdateRecordAsync(
    Zone As Zone,
    RecordType As DnsRecordType,
    RecordContent As String,
    DnsRecords As IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord)
  ) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))

    Dim oModifiedRecord As ModifiedDnsRecord
    Dim oCurrentRecord As DnsRecord
    Dim oCfResult As CloudFlareResult(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    oModifiedRecord = New ModifiedDnsRecord With {.Type = RecordType, .Name = DnsRecords.First.Name, .Content = RecordContent}
    oCfResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.UpdateAsync(Zone.Id, DnsRecords.First.Id, oModifiedRecord)

    If oCfResult.Success Then
      oResult = oCfResult.Result.ToResult

      ' Clean up any stale duplicates
      For Each oCurrentRecord In DnsRecords.Skip(1)
        oResult = Await Me.DeleteRecordAsync(Zone, oCurrentRecord)
        If oResult.IsFailed Then Exit For
      Next
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oCfResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function DeleteRecordAsync(Zone As Zone, Record As DnsRecord) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oCfResult As CloudFlareResult(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    oCfResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.DeleteAsync(Zone.Id, Record.Id)

    If oCfResult.Success Then
      oResult = oCfResult.Result.ToResult
    Else
      oResult = Result.Fail(oCfResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private Async Function DeleteRecordsAsync(Zone As Zone, DnsRecords As IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord)) As Task(Of Result(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oCurrentRecord As DnsRecord
    Dim oResult As Result(Of DnsRecord)

    oResult = Result.Ok

    If DnsRecords.Any Then
      Await Me.DeleteRecordAsync(Zone, DnsRecords.First)

      ' Clean up any stale duplicates
      For Each oCurrentRecord In DnsRecords.Skip(1)
        oResult = Await Me.DeleteRecordAsync(Zone, oCurrentRecord)
        If oResult.IsFailed Then Exit For
      Next
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function

  Private ReadOnly Client As ICloudFlareClient
End Class

Extensions
Public Module Depot
  <Extension>
  Public Function [Call](Of TIn, TOut)(Instance As Result(Of TIn), Target As Func(Of TIn, Result(Of TOut))) As Result(Of TOut)
    Return If(Instance.IsSuccess, Target.Invoke(Instance.Value), Result.Fail(Of TOut)(Instance.Errors))
  End Function

  <Extension>
  Public Async Function CallAsync(Of TIn, TOut)(Instance As Result(Of TIn), Target As Func(Of TIn, Task(Of Result(Of TOut)))) As Task(Of Result(Of TOut))
    Return If(Instance.IsSuccess, Await Target.InvokeAsync(Instance.Value), Result.Fail(Of TOut)(Instance.Errors))
  End Function

  <Extension>
  Public Function TryCatch(Of TIn, TOut)(Instance As Result(Of TIn), Target As Func(Of TIn, TOut)) As Result(Of TOut)
    Dim oError As [Error]

    Try
      TryCatch = If(Instance.IsSuccess, Result.Ok(Target.Invoke(Instance.Value)), Result.Fail(Of TOut)(Instance.Errors))

    Catch ex As Exception
      oError = New [Error](ex.Message)
      oError.CausedBy(ex)
      Instance.Errors.Add(oError)

      TryCatch = Result.Fail(Of TOut)(Instance.Errors)

    End Try
  End Function

  <Extension>
  Public Function Tap(Of TIn)(Instance As Result(Of TIn), Target As Action(Of TIn)) As Result(Of TIn)
    If Instance.IsSuccess Then
      Target.Invoke(Instance.Value)
    End If

    Return Instance
  End Function

  <Extension>
  Public Function Match(Of TIn, TOut)(Instance As Result(Of TIn), OnSuccess As Func(Of TIn, TOut), OnFailure As Func(Of List(Of IError), TOut)) As TOut
    Return If(Instance.IsSuccess, OnSuccess.Invoke(Instance.Value), OnFailure.Invoke(Instance.Errors))
  End Function
End Module


This is tricky code indeed.
You can return early (surely there is a name for that pattern) eg:
  Friend Async Function CleanupAsync(City As City) As Task(Of Result) Implements IDnsService.CleanupAsync
    Dim oDnsRecordsResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of DnsRecord))
    Dim oDnsRecordResult As CloudFlareResult(Of DnsRecord)
    Dim oCurrentRecord As DnsRecord
    Dim oZonesResult As CloudFlareResult(Of IReadOnlyList(Of Zone))
    Dim oDnsRecord As (Type As DnsRecordType, Name As String)
    Dim oFilter As DnsRecordFilter
    Dim oResult As Result
    Dim oZone As Zone

    oDnsRecord.Type = DnsRecordType.Txt
    oDnsRecord.Name = City.AcmeChallengeDnsName

    oZonesResult = Await Me.Client.Zones.GetAsync

    If Not oZonesResult.Success Then
        Return Result.Fail(oZonesResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    ' proceed...
    
    oZone = oZonesResult.Result.First
    oFilter = New DnsRecordFilter With {.Type = oDnsRecord.Type, .Name = oDnsRecord.Name}
    oDnsRecordsResult = Me.Client.Zones.DnsRecords.GetAsync(oZone.Id, oFilter).Result

    If Not oDnsRecordsResult.Success Then
      Return Result.Fail(oZonesResult.Errors.Select(Function(Err) Err.Message))
    End If

    ' proceed...

  End Function

This is a quick PoC, not tested code.
The idea here is to undo the nesting and to test for errors, step by step. If an error (or unwanted condition) occurs you return immediately. Otherwise you proceed to the next step. So you end up with small blocks of code that are related but still detached from each other.
The disadvantage in that pattern is that you have multiple return points. But if your control structure is too complex (too much nesting) there could be uncovered conditions too. This is where a code coverage tool (SonarQube?) and unit tests come in.

I think early conditional returns are called "guard clauses", although I'm not sure if this is still an appropriate name if the function only consists of a long list of such returns

Yes, the guard pattern, but I set a convention for myself long ago to always have one and only one return path. No multiples, as you point out. It's so easy to overlook a stray return when analyzing or debugging code, so I prefer to avoid that risk. It's one less thing to have to worry about. Of course that then tends at first blush to produce our famous Arrowhead antipattern, to which we must respond by introducing yet a different complexity. So in the end it all boils down to "choose your poison," I suppose.

But thank you for the suggestion

Multiple returns in a function is not a problem provided the code is understandable.
